# I need the google assistant to be able to fill out a google form

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a basic form. I use to help organize my spending habits. I manually fill it out every day with things like  date, description, cost, and category of things that I purchase. It drops the data into a google sheet that I use for analysis at regular intervals.

Rather than having to manually type out all of this information, it would make logical sense that I should be able to use a google assistant action to fill out this form for my by talking to it. However there doesn't seem to be any straightforward connection from the google assistant to filling out google forms.

Is there a way to connect these in a straightforward way with the assistant sdk?

Comment: Do you mean the Assistant SDK, which lets you build devices that have the Assistant in them, or Actions on Google, which let you build Actions that you can converse with through the Google Assistant?

Comment: @Prisoner I believe tis should be an action that I can converse with the google assistant

Comment: That is, strictly speaking, out of scope for StackOverflow, which deals with programming and related developer questions. If you are looking to write that feature yourself - SO is an appropriate place to do so. (That said, check out something like vodo-drive.com, which does provide voice conversations with sheets through an action.) (Disclaimer - I wrote Vodo Drive.)

Comment: I don't believe Google Forms has an API for being filled out, but Google Sheets does have an API for inserting new data so you may want to consider investigating that path.